# How to use git add or git lfs track A LOT of files

Tags: git, bash, unix, arguments, git-lfs

My directory structure is as such with lots of files with `.xyz` extension:

```
/outerdir-123
    /123456a
       abc.xyz
    /123457b
       lmn.xyz
       opq.xyz
    /999998c
       def.xyz
       ghi.xyz
       lop.xyz
```

When I tried to do:

```
git lfs track outerdir-123/**
```

or when I try to add the files:

```
git add outerdir-123/**
```

It throws a

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/git: Argument list too long
```

There are around 100,000 inner directories and each directory contains 1 to 20 `.xyz` files.

The files are small enough (< 10MB each) so they should be able to fit into the git repository.

**How to use `git add` or `git lfs track` A LOT of files and subdirectories in `outerdir-123`?** Is that possible at all?

**Should I write a script and just add/track each subdirectory individually?**

Comment: Just use `git lfs track outerdir-123`? The issue isn't with `git`, it's with the maximum length of an argument list once the glob is expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use double quotes for the lfs:

```
git lfs track "outerdir-123/**"
```

And just the directory name for the add:

```
git add outerdir-123
```

Comment: `git add outerdir-123` for ~1M files is not trivial though, it's been 2 hours and it's still adding.

Comment: i think this is the best method to use when working with Github. i have been getting headaches because of this. but  you so much for the solution